# Alerts for incoming emails in shared mailbox

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-2003

Is there any way to set up alerts for emails arriving in a shared mailbox? We use shared mailboxes at our company a lot and the downside is that users have to manually check on them all the time.

It would be cool to get a desktop alert, like you get when a mail arrives in your primary mailbox. Is there a clever way to do this?

We are in a Exchange 2003 / Outlook 2003 environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  See my answer in [Create Exchange 2003 server side rule without logging in as user](https://serverfault.com/questions/192401/create-exchange-2003-server-side-rule-without-logging-in-as-user/192889#192889)

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to test right now, but if you setup a outlook profile for that shared mailbox, login, setup the alert you want (maybe get it to send a email to your proper account, whatever u want really).

So in more detail no XP Pro:
Start->Control Panel->Mail->Show Profiles->Add->"A Name"->Add New account->Fill in the usual details->Finish

Don't foret to switch on Select at startup which profile you want to run:
Start->Control Panel->Mail->Show Profiles->Select the Radio Button for "Prompt for a profile to be used"

Next time you start outlook it will ask you for the profile, pick your shared email account. Setup the alerts you want, log back in with your own account and thats it, i think

From the top of my head right now, but roughly right I think (also depends how your exchange and shared boxes are setup)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I set up a rule in the shared mailbox to display a Desktop Alert and also made sure that Desktop Alerts are turned on in Advanced E-mail Options.

It works when I have only the shared mailbox open in the new profile, however when added as an additional mailbox, it doesn't display any alert - only the ones set up for my primary mailbox.

So it seems that the only way to set up an alert is by sending an email every time there is a new mail. Which is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: No, that won't work.  Alerts only work with your profile's primary mailbox which is typically your own personal mailbox.

Comment: You could always just add the rule that checks if its relivent to what you want to know about, then it would email to your main account and if required a rule there checks to see if you want to be alerted, if not just send it to the trash?

Ok so you increase mail traffic a bit, but u will get the alerts you want without 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of mailbox checking programs around. They nearly all use the POP3 protocol, which would normally be of no value in this case, but I do recall seeing a couple over the years which keep a log of the messages, allowing the program to alert only for messages that have arrived since the last alert was acknowledged. You'll need to do a bit of searching to find the right program but I believe a copy of that on each person's machine will solve your problems, as each person will receive alerts independently of others sharing the same mailbox(es).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to do this natively with Outlook 2003.  Outlook monitors only the profile's primary mailbox, not additional mailboxes that you open in your profile.  You would need to either write something custom or find a third party component that would monitor the mailbox and display an alert for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simon Catlin is right.  It's a drag though.

If you can get away with just forwarding the messages to a group, that is easier than trying to set up notifications.  Unfortunately for my question, I can't so we are paying someone to do the development for us...